# Android Studio not opening even after trying multiple times

Tags: android

My android studio is not at all opening directly or from command line.

Earlier my JAVA_HOME and JDK_HOME variables were not set so I followed the instructions [here](https://techglimpse.com/google-android-studio-launching-fix-windows/#:%7E:text=%20To%20fix%2C%20follow%20the%20below%20steps%3A%20,step%20is%20very%20important%2C%20as%20the...%20More%20) and everything seemed to be working fine, I even got "Already running" from my command prompt but android studio is still not opening.

I have even tried uninstalling and installing it again.

Can anyone point out what the reason could be and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Go to this_pc < C: drive < users < `your user name (in my case alok7)` > appdata > local > android.

**OR**

> C:\Users\alok7\AppData\Local\Android

then clear/delete all data